# Jasmine spyOn function within function and return mock value from last fn call

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to write a Jasmine test where I got an object structure as follows:

```js
class User {
   public getData(): void {
      return {
         getPersonalInfo: () => {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Normally, I would call this as user.getData().getPersonalInfo(). Now, I would like to spyOn this call and return a mocked info response when calling `getPersonalInfo()`.

What I attempted doing:

```js
spyOn(user.getData, "getPersonalInfo").and.returnValue(...)

spyOn(user, "getData").and.callThrough().and.callFake(() => {... fake data ...} )

spyOn(user, "getPersonalInfo").and.callFake(() => {... fake data ...} )
```

But no matter what I have tried thus far, it's not working.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can archive it like this:

```js
const getPersonalInfoSpy = jasmine.createSpy('getPersonalInfoSpy');
getPersonalInfoSpy.and.returnValue({}); // provide mock here
spyOn(user, "getData").and.returnValue({ getPersonalInfo: getPersonalInfoSpy})
```

Don't forget to provide a proper mock for `getPersonalInfoSpy`;